# How to add Footer in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I have a common.xsl file in which I have defined all the templates, what am basically planning to do is to have footers for all the off pages generated from xsl. Am new to xsl can any one please provide me a good example to start with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add header and footer for every pages in xsl-fo to generate pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657579/how-to-add-header-and-footer-for-every-pages-in-xsl-fo-to-generate-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but in a nutshell, the fo side of xsl is where you would define the rules and formatting for a footer on a page. If you look at an xsl fo [example](http://www.ecrion.com/help/products/xfrenderingserver/xfultrascalehelp4/example_1.htm), near the top is the declarations for the types of pages that the template is able to generate (this can be one generic page but you can define as many as you like). In the simple-page-master declaration, you can define regions which represent the body of the content, and the four outer edges. In your case, you would add a definition for the region-after (this is the bottom edge, or in your case, the footer of the page). You define the content and formatting in your page sequence so that, as your render engine is processing pages, it knows that part of the sequence for that page is generating the footer content. See the example I referenced for more precise implementation details, but conceptually, this is the key concept to understand.

Answer (score 0):

USE J4L FO Designer Trial version is available and you can simply copy code which is generated in FO ...
Each item will be display in header and footer after that.